# Remap broken "Tab" key to a function key on MacOs Sierra

Tags: keyboard

I need to remap the tab key to a function key, as the Tab is broken. I've looked at [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), but it doesn't work on Sierra

Comment: Have you looked at [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)? I haven't used it directly, but it's the new version being developed for macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Karabiner does not work in MacOS Sierra they offer [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md) which has a subset of Karabiner's features.

One of the features it **does** have is the ability to map a function key to <kbd>tab</kbd>.